# Не работает сортировка разных массивов

Tags: javascript, api

Надо отсортировать массивы, по убыванию возраста.
Я их отсортировал, но почему они не отсортировались?

Входить надо, через контакт

http://plnkr.co/edit/IbIIILTDthMoKtoO9Yhc?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js"></script>

    <script>

    function foo() {

    VK.init({
            apiId: 5580872
        });


    VK.Auth.login(function(response){

        if(response.session){



            VK.api('friends.get', {'user_id' : '26291131', 'fields' : 'bdate'}, response => {
                if(response.error){
                    alert(response.error.error_msg);
                }
                else{
                    let userData = response.response;
                    var arrUser = []
                    var arrAge = [];
                    var arrAge2 = [];
                    var now = new Date(); 
                    var god = now.getFullYear()




                    for(var h = 0; h < userData.length; h++){
                        arrUser.push(userData[h].first_name + ' ' + userData[h].last_name)

                        if(typeof userData[h].bdate == 'string' && userData[h].bdate.split('.')[2]){
                        arrAge.push(userData[h].first_name + ' ' + userData[h].last_name + ' ' + (god - parseInt((userData[h].first_name + ' ' + userData[h].last_name + ' ' + userData[h].bdate.split('.')[2]).split(' ')[2])))

                        }
                    }

                    for(var c = 0; c < arrAge.length; c++){
                        arrAge2.push(arrAge[c].split(' '))

                    }


                    //сортировка по возрасту

                    arrAge2.sort(function(a,b){
                       return a[2] < b[2];
                    });


                    arrAge2.forEach(function(el){
                     console.log(el);
                    });

                }
            });


        }
        else{
            alert('Не удалось авторизироваться')
        }
    }, 2);
}
foo()


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Вот пример на подобии, который тоже почему-то не работает

```
var arr = [
    ['firstname1', 'lasname1', '26'],
    ['firstname2', 'lastname2', '14'],
    ['firstname3', 'lasme3', '22'],
    ['firstname3', 'laname3', '22'],
    ['firstname4', 'lasame4', '23'],
    ['firstname2', 'lastname2', '14'],
    ['firstname5', 'lastnme5', '20']
];

console.log(arr.sort((a, b) => b[0] < a[0]))
```